# Github Action: how to get previous GitHub action run result into my current run

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I have a GitHub workflow that kickoff when PR is created/synchronize/reopened

```
name: CI Deployment
on:
    pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

concurrency: 
    group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.ref }}
    cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
    stageA:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name: Commit SHA
        run: |
            echo "pass"
    stageB:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name: Commit SHA
        run: |
            echo "fail"
            exit 1
```

For the first run suppose stageB has failed. How can I get the result of stageA which is passed so I can skip that build and run only stageB.

P.S I know GitHub provided an option to `re-run failed job` from UI but the above use case is just an example my real use case is a little complicated for which I need the result of the previous run result so my bash script runs accordingly.

Comment: Kindly correct if my understanding is wrong, what you want is to get the status of `stageA` in `stageB` in the same run, or it is over to the subsequent run(next execution of pipeline).

Comment: @ChetanTalwar I want the status in the next execution of the pipeline. Or you can say I need previous execution status on my current execution

Comment: How about using the cache?

Comment: @rethab How to cache execution results??

Comment: Here's the action you could use: https://github.com/actions/cache

Answer (score 0):

use the [github cli command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_view) `gh run view PREVIOUS_WORKFLOW_RUN_NUMBER`in your workflow to get the infos of the previous run. and for your example use the options  `-j, --job <string> View a specific job ID from a run`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a workflow run with `Server` job and `Client` job. `Notification` will be run after both the two jobs are done. In the `Notification` job, you would like to send Slack notification only if the current run conclusion (success/failure/cancelled) is different from the previous conclusion in the previous GitHub Actions run.

Prepare

```
secrets.YOUR_REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN
secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN
vars.SLACK_CHANNEL_ID
```

and in your workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  Server:
    ...
  Client:
    ...
  Notification:
    runs-on: Linux
    needs: [Server, Client]
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name and committer name
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "branch=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          THE_COMMITTER_NAME="${{ github.event.head_commit.author.name }}"
          _THE_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${{ github.event.head_commit.author.email }}"
          THE_COMMITTER="${_THE_COMMITTER_EMAIL%@*}"
          echo "committer_handle=${THE_COMMITTER}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "workflow_name=${GITHUB_WORKFLOW}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        id: extract_info
      - name: Check prev and curr run status
        id: run_status
        run: |
          PREV_CONCLUSION_=$( \
            curl -s -X GET \
              -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.YOUR_REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN || github.token }}' \
              -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
              '${{ github.api_url }}/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs?status=completed&page=1&branch=${{ steps.extract_info.outputs.branch }}' | \
            jq -r 'first(.workflow_runs[] | select(.conclusion!="cancelled") | select (.name=="${{ steps.extract_info.outputs.workflow_name }}")).conclusion' \
          )
          echo "prev_conclusion=${PREV_CONCLUSION_}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

          if [[ "${{ needs.Server.result }}" == "failure" || "${{ needs.Client.result }}" == "failure" ]]; then
            echo "curr_conclusion=failure" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          elif [[ "${{ needs.Server.result }}" == "cancelled" || "${{ needs.Client.result }}" == "cancelled" ]]; then
            echo "curr_conclusion=cancelled" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "curr_conclusion=success" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
      - name: Send Slack Notification
        uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.18.0
        with:
          # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context
          # https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder
          channel-id: ${{ vars.SLACK_CHANNEL_ID }}
          payload: |
            {
              "text": "<@${{ steps.extract_info.outputs.committer_handle }}> touched ${{ github.repository }}/${{ steps.extract_info.outputs.branch }}.\nStatus: ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.prev_conclusion }} -> ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion }} ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion == 'success' && ':tada:' || ':thinking_face:' }}.",
              "blocks": [
                {
                  "type": "section",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "type": "mrkdwn",
                      "text": "<@${{ steps.extract_info.outputs.committer_handle }}> <${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}|touched> ${{ github.repository }}/${{ steps.extract_info.outputs.branch }}.\nLint Status: ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.prev_conclusion }} -> ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion }} ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion == 'success' && ':tada:' || ':thinking_face:' }}. "
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
        env:
          SLACK_BOT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN }}
        if: ${{ steps.run_status.outputs.prev_conclusion != steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion && !((steps.run_status.outputs.prev_conclusion == '' && steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion == 'success') || (steps.run_status.outputs.curr_conclusion == 'cancelled')) }}
```

This is really tricky but we have to do this as the `github` context doesn't provide any details about previous action runs.

Reported to GitHub: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/101518